# Using Sourcemaps with google chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, less, google-chrome-devtools

i have tried to configure sourcemaps in less files. When I inspect an Element I see the correct less file with the file extension. So it seems to work

But when I do changes the file name for Example style.less:1120 change to style.css:129

What went wrong?

Another problem is, that chrome shows me only the style.less file. This file imports only my components. So instead of seeing component.less:10 i see style.less:221

My gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var rename = require('gulp-rename'); 
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

var paths = {
  scripts: ['client/js/**/*.coffee', '!client/external/**/*.coffee'],
  images: 'client/img/**/*',
  less: 'web/style/style.less'
}; 

gulp.task('less' , function() {
  // Minify and copy all JavaScript (except vendor scripts) 
  // with sourcemaps all the way down 
  return gulp.src(paths.less)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(less())
      .pipe(rename(function(path) {
        path.extname = ".css";
      }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('web/style/.'));
});

// Rerun the task when a file changes 
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.less, ['less']);
});

// The default task (called when you run `gulp` from cli) 
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Comment: How do you generate the sourcemaps and where do you see the style.less:1120 and style.css:129? also how do you include them in the HTML?

Comment: i see the style.less:1120 in google chrome. in the devtools, after inspect an element.

Comment: Okay. First please try out other browsers. Then compile the less files manually from command line and see if there's a difference. I have never used gulp, but maybe it's setting some wrong options. Also see https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1715#issuecomment-35825756